# why does my arc doesn't grow every frame?

Tags: javascript, html, function, animation, canvas

I am trying to make an animation of a sunrise, so for that i need a circle that grows in size. At the moment i'm using an arc, but my sun isnt growing every frame so it just stays static. I've tried calling another function but I'm not sure how to do that or if the code I've already made is missing something. This is the code I've written so far.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Animacion</title>
</head>

<body onload="call()">
  <!--canvas-->
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
  <script>
    function call() {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

    function draw() {
      //context
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
      ctx.fillStyle = "green";
      ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
      ctx.save();

      //ground
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(0, 200, 300, 100);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.save();

      //sun size    
      var sunSize = 50;
      //sun
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
      ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
      ctx.arc(145, 220, sunSize, sunSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      sunSize = sunSize + 5;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.save();
      //sky
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = "cyan";
      ctx.fillStyle = "cyan";
      ctx.rect(0, 0, 300, 300);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.save();


      window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
    call();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried using another function inside of the `draw()` but it basically does nothing and erases the sky i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you initalize `sunSize` inside your `draw()` function so it resets the `sunSize` to 50 every time it runs. move the `sunSize` outside the draw function below the `<script>` part here;

```
<script>
      var sunSize = 50;
        function call(){
            window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        }
etc, etc
```

also, instad of using `sunSize = sunSize + 5` use `sunSize += 5`. they mean the exact same thing just written faster. 5 may be a bit fast though. try using 0.1 or 0.2

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I've been struggling waaaaay too much with this, now it finally works, thank you!